# Remove a specific part of a string with an identifier

Tags: javascript, string, typescript

I have a string where I need to remove the first `:familyCodes:xxxxx` that appears after the `:false` (the `:false` always appears)

For example this:

```
excludedFromIndex:false:familyCodes:13337:familyCodes:13341
```

Should be:

```
excludedFromIndex:false:familyCodes:13341
```

Is there any js function I could use?

Thanks

Comment: `replace` would probably work. May you share your effort so far?

Comment: In what context do you have this string? How is it generated/retrieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to achieve this, for example:

```
const regEx = /:familyCodes:[\d]+/;
const str = 'excludedFromIndex:false:familyCodes:13337:familyCodes:13341';
const result = str.replace(regEx, '');
console.log(result);
```

This will remove the first occurrence of `:familyCodes:xxxxx:` (where `xxxxx` will match any number of digits 0-9).